# Decimal to Hex resulting in 0xDecimal number

Tags: python

I need to sum a hex number with an int one. Bot numbers are given as strings:

The following code

```py
result = hex(int("12", 16) + int("3", 16))
print(result)
```

yields:

```py
0x15 # instead of 0xF
```

Any idea on how to obtain `0xF` instead of `0x15`?

Comment: `int("12", 16)` != 12. It's 18.

Comment: Damm, I forgot that, I got confused with both results being similar: dec 12+3=15 and 0x12+3=0x15. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer Python gave you is correct. `0x12 + 3 = 0x15`. Your problem is that you read `0x12` as `12` when you calculated it in your head, when it's actually `18`.

An additional problem you will have is that you're treating *both* numbers as hex numbers. You only need `int("3")` for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as expected, you just assumed that 12 in hexadecimal is equal to 12 in decimal which is not.

```
result = hex(int('C', 16) + int('3', 16))
print(result)
```

0xC=12
0x12=18

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Explain what you're showing.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this one is so simple that code will explain everything.